# php - drop down from database

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Im a newbie ih php.Im trying to show drop down list values from database using [this](http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/drop-down-menu-populated-from-a-mysql-database-1811.html) but the data not shown up.There is no error as well. Need some experts advice.

Code

```
      <?php

include('connectdb.php');     
$sql="SELECT id,name FROM companydetailstbl";
$result=mysql_query($sql);    
$options="";    
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
    $id=$row["id"];
    //echo $id;
    $thing=$row["name"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing;
}
?>
        <table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="22%">Company Name </td>
            <td width="3%">:</td>
            <td width="75%"><SELECT NAME="thing">
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
<?=$options?>
</SELECT></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Installation Date </td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ins_dt" />
            (ddmmyyyy)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Expiry Date </td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ex_dt" />
            (ddmmyyyy)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: The code you are copying is from 2002. PHP and html have evolved quite a bit so you might want to look for something fresher.

Comment: Also, have you looked at the source code, is the information there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what DTD you are currently using, but according to the [HTML 4.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION), you need to close your `option` tag.

```
$options .= '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $thing . '</option>';
```

Also there,

```
<select name="thing">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
    <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Damn it, you beat me to is :) I was about to post essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

please try to close the tag

```
 $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing."</OPTION>";
```

also edit

```
<SELECT NAME="thing">
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose</OPTION>
<?=$options?>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include('connectdb.php');     
$sql="SELECT id,name FROM companydetailstbl";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>

<table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="22%">Company Name </td>
        <td width="3%">:</td>
        <td width="75%">
            <select name="thing">
            <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
            ?>
                    <option value="<?=$row["id"]; ?>"><?=$row["name"]; ?></option>
            <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Installation Date </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ins_dt" />(ddmmyyyy)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Expiry Date </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ex_dt" />(ddmmyyyy)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Reset" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps